# Visual Basic How to get sum of all checked checkboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have given each checkbox item on my application a value. I have group of checkboxes and I need to add up their total value base on user selection. I am using this code but it's not working for sum. I do not want to use if a.checked then add this elseif this checked add that kind of way.

```
   Dim abe As CheckBox = groupAlumni.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().Where(Function(r) r.Checked = True).Sum()
    MsgBox(abe.Tag)
```

.sum part is giving an error. How can I achieve this?

Option 2
Also I am thinking I could change checkbox names to cb0 to cb15 and create a while loop and check them one by one to see which ones are selected and add up their values. How can I change cb number during while loop?

I wrote this but I really need cb0 to be cb1,cb2 and continue until cb15 during the loop.

If anybody answers either option it's fine for me. Thank you!

```
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim cbScore As Integer = 0

    While counter < 15
        If cb0.Checked Then
            cbScore += cb0.Tag
        End If

        counter += 1
    End While
```

Comment: does vba do LINQ now?

Comment: what does linq mean?

Comment: What are you summing?

Comment: I have bunch of checkboxes on the application. All of them have values in their tag property. I need to sum checked ones values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the sum of the values, try this:

`cbScore = groupAlumni.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().Where(Function(r) r.Checked).Sum(Function(r) CInt(r.Tag))`

Comment: Beeautiful! Thank you!!

Comment: I can't use that for radio buttons though, how do I make that work with radio buttons? I have this code it wont work Dim scoreSAT As RadioButton = groupSAT.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().Where(Function(r) r.Checked = True).FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Try to use Single instead of Where and drop the FirstOrDefault. This should return the checked RadioButton. Then you can read the Tag property.

Answer (score -1):

Removed due to not compiling and incompatible methods.

Comment: In each VB (text) file of source code of the various things you are coding (classes, forms, etc.), and at the very top, add a line containing "**Option Strict On**" (without quotes), then another line "**Option Explicit On**", and a last one "**Option Infer Off**". Then try to recompile (any of) your projects. This will greatly help you to learn how to code better .. and tells you one third of the _"what's wrong with your answer"_.

Comment: The other issues are : the use of VB `Replace` instead of `String.Replace`. Someone that started learning dotNet with C# won't guess what's the meaning of Replace and assumes it's not dotNet. So, either make explicit mention of the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace on top of your answer, either delete that reference immediately after creating a project in the IDE, either use the provided String.Replace function. So ? What does Replace because I don't know.

Comment: Then in your Replace(..) : `(cb + "counter")` ??? shouldn't be `("cb" + counter)` ? cb is a string, then I assume Replace returns a String. But soon enough, you have cb.Checked and cb.Tag... Checked and Tag are not members of the String Type ! You have very very strange ways of infering types in your code :/

Comment: I didn't downvote though, because I couldn't (not enough reputation) but I really should. Answers has to compile right to start with. So you asked why someone downvoted.. because of the above. Trying to give answers is a good thing. But giving answers that will add more issues to the OP isn't. Yes, I'm also here to learn how to code better and I'm not an expert like you. One way of learning is by reading questions and answers of others. I don't answer questions that I don't understand, or when I'm unsure my solution will work.

Comment: Thank you for commenting on what was wrong with the code. I see now that I was in too much of a hurry to provide an answer without double checking various aspects of it. You're absolutely right on the Checked and Tag methods not working with String. If someone could remove my answer who has the authority to do so please remove it as I'm as of yet unsure how to fix it correctly.